# Felgo 4 Android Orientation bug

Tags: android, orientation, felgo

> 

Hello

I am building an Android application using Clang Qt 6.4.1 armeabi-v7a. However, on other devices such as the Pixel 4 (Android 13) I get a “blank space” appearing on the right at at the bottom of the application when I change the orientation of the device from Portrait to Landscape and vice versa. Here are some photos;

The app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mJqAhuD057NpcaHBrsdEIi0jYGLdTe9Z/view?usp=drivesdk

When flipped horizontally: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m6o4rF59u9ABez2wUEItS0t6ax3hH2p-/view?usp=drivesdk

The issue is in the second image. Is this a bug? What do you recommend? Should I try use Felgo for Qt 5 instead??

When the device's orientation changes from Potrait to Landscape, I expected the Felgo App to adapt accordingly as it does on the Felgo Mobile App.
But instead, when I run on debug and install into device and change orientation some extra space appears on the right.

See picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m6o4rF59u9ABez2wUEItS0t6ax3hH2p-/view?usp=drivesdk